# Does user have to download ADO.net when using c# application which contains sqlite Databases

Tags: c#, sqlite

Question is regarding ADO.NET 2.0 sqlite provider for c#.

I have a c# desktop application  which I created using winforms. In this I used an sqlite database using ADO.net. If I ever want to view it's contents I do so using Firefox.

I don't know much about how it works but **my question is:**

If I make this app portable (i.e users from other desktops can download it) will the sqlite part also be present on their desktop? Or will they have to separately download the ADO.NET package as well?

Comment: ADO.Net is part of .Net.  SQLite isn't.

Comment: You should deploy non-standard DLLs with your application.